# Align DIVs centered and next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I am making a gallery and am stuck on a problem.
I want to have thumbnails of images next to eachother, in the center, I also want to have different groups which are under eachother.

Here's what I have: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wb6q/).

How do I make group 1 and 2's images centered and next to eachother and how can I make group 2 under group 1?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code without JsFiddle:
  Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Group 1: <br>
        <div class="img">
            <a href="img/een.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
                <img src="img/een.jpg" alt="Een" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <a href="img/twee.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
                <img src="img/twee.jpg" alt="Twee" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </div>
        <br>

        Group 2: <br>

        <div class="img">
            <a href="img/drie.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
                <img src="img/drie.jpg" alt="Drie" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a href="img/vier.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
                <img src="img/vier.jpg" alt="Vier" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your groups in a div.

HTML

```
   <div class="group">
      Group 1: <br>
      <div class="img">
        <a href="img/een.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
         <img src="img/een.jpg" alt="Een" width="100" height="100">
         </a>
       </div>

        <div class="img">
          <a href="img/twee.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
         <img src="img/twee.jpg" alt="Twee" width="100" height="100">
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div.img {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/tMTG3/)

Answer (score 0):

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wb6q/2/)

Slightly amend your HTML and CSS to the below. Crucially you want to wrap your `img` within a parent element with `text-align:center;` set, you can accomplish this using e.g. the below ([see here for centred titles](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wb6q/4/)):

```
Group 1:
<br>
<div class="img"> <a href="img/een.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
      <img src="img/een.jpg" alt="Een" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
 <a href="img/twee.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
      <img src="img/twee.jpg" alt="Twee" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>

</div>
Group 2:
<br>
<div class="img"> <a href="img/drie.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
      <img src="img/drie.jpg" alt="Drie" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
 <a href="img/vier.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
      <img src="img/vier.jpg" alt="Vier" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.img {
    text-align:center;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
div.img a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can fit such a decision

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwzxb)

```
    <div class="galleryItem">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgsrc.ru/images/reco/140/windkitten_38083968.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
.........

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryItem {
    color: #797478;
    font: 10px/1.5 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
}

.galleryItem h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.galleryItem img {
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.galleryItem {
    color: #797478;
    font: 10px/1.5 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;    

    width: 16%;
    margin:  2% 2% 50px 2%; 
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 940px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 940px){
    .galleryItem {width: 21%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 720px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 720px){
    .galleryItem {width: 29.33333%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 530px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 530px){
    .galleryItem {width: 46%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 320px){
    .galleryItem {width: 96%;}
    .galleryItem img {width: 96%;}
    .galleryItem h3 {font-size: 18px;}
    .galleryItem p, {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To centralize the images**, place a wrapper div around them.

**To ensure that group 2 is below group 1**, you can either place a div with CSS clear property after the first group or use the CSS after selector to get the same effect without actually changing the html.

*(In this sample code, I am inserting an extra div after the first group.)*

**HTML**
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Group 1:

```
<div class="img">
  <a href="img/twee.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-1">
    <img src="img/twee.jpg" alt="Twee" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
</div>
<br>

<div class='clearfix'></div>

Group 2: <br>

<div class="img">
  <a href="img/drie.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
    <img src="img/drie.jpg" alt="Drie" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a href="img/vier.jpg" data-lightbox="Group-2">
    <img src="img/vier.jpg" alt="Vier" width="100" height="100" />
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div.img {
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
text-align:center;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}

div.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
```

*(Please note that you should always use a slash before closing the img tag)*